# YUM RHEL Update Server

Tags: yum, redhat, update, rhn

I need to create a local RHEL5 Update Server to help eliminate the number of servers exposed to the web. All the local rhel5 servers need to be able to use this server as a repository for patches. I have a server registered with Redhat and would like to use yum to accomplish this. It is possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think the project you are looking for is called [spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/download.html) and allows you to run your own server for the Red Hat system management software.  However, AFAIK this **replaces** rather than works in conjunction with the Red Hat servers.  If you want an in-house server that inter-operates with the Red Hat servers, speak to sales at Red Hat.  They have a product for that called RHN Satellite, but I haven't used it.

Here's a link to [RHN Satellite](http://www.redhat.com/red_hat_network/), thanks for the pointer weeheavy.

Comment: Yeah, it's called RHN Satellite.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.Space Walk is known to me. Space Walk is only available for CentOS systems and not für RHEL. For RHEL Red Hat has the Satelite-Server, but this is to expensive, so I want to configure my own Update-Reporitory.

Comment: @Marcus, I think you're stuck between a rock and a hard place...  Spacewalk is the open-sourced Satellite, as I understand it, so I think it's going to be the closest you can get to the hybrid you are looking for.

Comment: I think you understood me.  I wan´t use a extra tool like Spacewalk or Satellite. I will install a "Update-Server" which provide Updates for the internal Server which are in the intranet.

Comment: @Marcus: There's even a RHN Proxy, which costs $2500 per year (RHN Satellite: $13500/year. If this is too costly, you might want to update your question to reflect this.

Comment: Hi, what ist a RHN-Proxy? I found this Howto: http://fojta.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/rhel-local-repository/ But I think 2500$ per year is ok, if this Product is an Option.

Comment: @Marcus: see https://rhn.redhat.com/help/about.pxt (section "Architectures")

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, your answer ist very helpfuly. Where do U found the cost for the RHN-Proxy? On the Red Hat Homepage I don´t found anything :(

Comment: http://www.redhat.com/red_hat_network/faq/ title "How can I purchase RHN Satellite or Proxy server?"

Answer (score 1):

[mrepo](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/mrepo/) is what you need. A [howto](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/mrepo_configuration.html)

Comment: I've been using mrepo for several years now, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure Squid on the server to allow the proxying of Yum from the private subnet to the Redhat update servers. It can also cache packages, meaning it will only download a package once for all updates.

http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/squid/Configuring+a+Yum+Cache

Comment: I thought about suggesting that, but doesn't RHN operate over SSL?

Comment: hmm, you're probably right, I've never used RHN myself. I think a caching reverse-proxy should still be able to do it as it doesn't need to pretend to be the RHN server.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to imply that while you have multiple RHEL servers, only one is registered with RHN. If this is because you do not have subscriptions for those servers your question amounts to "how do I get more than I'm paying for?".

If your aim is genuinely to limit exposure, that problem is solved by firewalls...